# Python pandas save output to one single txt file

Tags: python, pandas

I try to clean multiple txt files and save the results as one txt file:

```
    import glob
    import errno
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import os
    from io import BytesIO
    import sys

    path = 'path/.../*.txt'
    files = glob.glob(path)
    for fname in files:
    #print(fname)
    with open(fname) as f:
        data = pd.read_csv(fname,header=None,sep=' ')
        base = os.path.basename(fname)
        os.path.splitext(base)
        shortname = os.path.splitext(base)[0]
        data = data.drop([1,2,3,4], axis=1)
        data = data.drop_duplicates()
        #print(data)
        data=data.reset_index(drop=True)
        #print(data)
        data = data.T
        #print(data)
        data.insert(0, 'name', shortname, True)
        #print(data)
        data.columns = data.iloc[0]
        print(data)
        pass # do what you want
    with open('C:/Users/yl0340/Desktop/clean/clean15.txt','a+') as f:
    print(data, file = f)
```

when I run it it gives me the output like this(I didn't show all of them):

```
    0  Shot9_010_559  19  4
    0  Shot9_011_157  19  4
    0  Shot9_011_157  19  4
    0  Shot9_012_235  19  4
    0  Shot9_012_235  19  4
    0  Shot9_013_288  19  4
    0  Shot9_013_288  19  4
    0  Shot9_014_79  19  4
    0  Shot9_014_79  19  4
    0  Shot9_015_335  19  4
    0  Shot9_015_335  19  4
    0  Shot9_016_268  0  19  4
    0  Shot9_016_268  0  19  4
    0  Shot9_017_399  16
    0  Shot9_017_399  16
    0  Shot9_018_189  2  19  18
    0  Shot9_018_189  2  19  18
    0  Shot9_019_399  19  2
    0  Shot9_019_399  19  2
```

I don't know the reason a "0" at the begin of each line. Also, as I open the output file(clean15.txt)it only shows the last line of the output, like:

```
    0  Shot9_019_399  19  2
```

I am not sure which part I did in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas will usually index your dataframes with an int. I can't tell exactly from your input which data you want to be the first value in your output file, but right before you export your dataframe to a file, try the following:

```
data.set_index('[the column you want as the index]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

You can create a dict with data from each file and shortnames as keys. At the end:

`pd.concat(mydict.values(), mydict.keys(), names=['shortname']).to_csv()`

Answer (score 0):

- Iterate through the files
- Clean the dataframe

  - None of the data cleaning steps have been changed, so the answer assumes `data` is a complete dataframe.
- Append `data` to a list of dataframes
- At the end, use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to combine the list of dataframes into a single dataframe
- Write the dataframe to a file with [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```py
import glob
import pandas as pd


path = 'path/.../*.txt'
files = glob.glob(path)
df_list = list()
for fname in files:
    data = pd.read_csv(fname, header=None,sep=' ')
    data = data.drop([1,2,3,4], axis=1)
    data = data.drop_duplicates()
    #print(data)
    data=data.reset_index(drop=True)
    #print(data)
    data = data.T
    #print(data)
    data.insert(0, 'name', shortname, True)
    #print(data)
    data.columns = data.iloc[0]
    print(data)
    df_list.append(data)
    
df = pd.concat(df_list)
df.to_csv('C:/Users/yl0340/Desktop/clean/clean_files.txt', index=False)
```